# From column of lists to a data frame in a tidyverse way in r

Tags: r, list, dataframe, dplyr, purrr

**PROBLEM:**
I want to convert a column from named lists into a data frame. However now there are only 9 items, problems will appear in other cases when variables in lists are up to 120. **So, is there an efficient way to extract all the variables in inside the lists without calling all one by one?**

**HERE IS THE `DPUT` FOR `FOO`:**

```r
foo <- structure(list(column_a = c("a", "b", "c"), column_b = list(list(country_code = "US", url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/geo/id/c3f37afa9efcf94b.json", country = "United States", place_type = "city", bounding_box = list(type = "Polygon", coordinates = structure(c(-97.928935, -97.928935, -97.580513, -97.580513, 30.127892, 30.518799, 30.518799, 30.127892), .Dim = c(1L, 4L, 2L))), full_name = "Austin, TX", attributes = structure(list(), .Names = character(0)), id = "c3f37afa9efcf94b", name = "Austin"), list(country_code = "UG", url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/geo/id/0092409a629e836c.json", country = "Uganda", place_type = "admin", bounding_box = list(type = "Polygon", coordinates = structure(c(32.192297, 32.192297, 32.683699, 32.683699, -0.147789, 0.585072, 0.585072, -0.147789), .Dim = c(1L, 4L, 2L))), full_name = "Wakiso, Uganda", attributes = structure(list(), .Names = character(0)), id = "0092409a629e836c", name = "Wakiso"), list(country_code = "US", url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/geo/id/080b8d8543aab399.json", country = "United States", place_type = "city", bounding_box = list(type = "Polygon", coordinates = structure(c(-93.399443, -93.399443, -93.203245, -93.203245, 44.78542, 44.863519, 44.863519, 44.78542), .Dim = c(1L, 4L, 2L))), full_name = "Bloomington, MN", attributes = structure(list(), .Names = character(0)), id = "080b8d8543aab399", name = "Bloomington"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

**DATA:**
My `foo` data frame has two columns `column_a` with letters and `column_b` which is a column of lists. Each list has 9 items.

```r
library(tidyverse)

foo
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>   column_a column_b        
#>   <chr>    <list>          
#> 1 a        <named list [9]>
#> 2 b        <named list [9]>
#> 3 c        <named list [9]>

str(foo[1,])
#> Classes 'tbl_df', 'tbl' and 'data.frame':    1 obs. of  2 variables:
#>  $ column_a: chr "a"
#>  $ column_b:List of 1
#>   ..$ :List of 9
#>   .. ..$ country_code: chr "US"
#>   .. ..$ url         : chr "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/geo/id/c3f37afa9efcf94b.json"
#>   .. ..$ country     : chr "United States"
#>   .. ..$ place_type  : chr "city"
#>   .. ..$ bounding_box:List of 2
#>   .. .. ..$ type       : chr "Polygon"
#>   .. .. ..$ coordinates: num [1, 1:4, 1:2] -97.9 -97.9 -97.6 -97.6 30.1 ...
#>   .. ..$ full_name   : chr "Austin, TX"
#>   .. ..$ attributes  : Named list()
#>   .. ..$ id          : chr "c3f37afa9efcf94b"
#>   .. ..$ name        : chr "Austin"
```

**SOLUTION A:** A solution is to call all the names of the variables in the lists and extract them using `map_chr` one by one.

```r
foo %>%
  mutate(
    country_code = map_chr(column_b, "country_code"),
    country = map_chr(column_b, "country")
  )
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>   column_a column_b         country_code country      
#>   <chr>    <list>           <chr>        <chr>        
#> 1 a        <named list [9]> US           United States
#> 2 b        <named list [9]> UG           Uganda       
#> 3 c        <named list [9]> US           United States
```

**SOLUTION B:** Following [this link](https://cfss.uchicago.edu/notes/simplify-nested-lists/), the solution is to call two times `map` function within `mutate`. But I had no success:

```r
foo %>%
  mutate(repo_info = column_b %>%
    map(~ .x %>%
      map_df(`[`, c("country_code", "country")))) %>%
  select(-column_b) %>%
  unnest()
#> # A tibble: 6 x 10
#>   column_a country_code url   country place_type bounding_box full_name
#>   <chr>    <chr>        <chr> <chr>   <chr>      <list>       <chr>    
#> 1 a        <NA>         <NA>  <NA>    <NA>       <NULL>       <NA>     
#> 2 a        <NA>         <NA>  <NA>    <NA>       <NULL>       <NA>     
#> 3 b        <NA>         <NA>  <NA>    <NA>       <NULL>       <NA>     
#> 4 b        <NA>         <NA>  <NA>    <NA>       <NULL>       <NA>     
#> 5 c        <NA>         <NA>  <NA>    <NA>       <NULL>       <NA>     
#> 6 c        <NA>         <NA>  <NA>    <NA>       <NULL>       <NA>     
#> # … with 3 more variables: attributes <list>, id <chr>, name <chr>
```

<sup>Created on 2019-08-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is after extracting the columns, convert to a `tibble` and then do the `unnest`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
foo %>%
   mutate(out = map(column_b,   ~ .x[c( "country_code", "country")] %>% 
               as_tibble)) %>% 
   unnest(out)
# A tibble: 3 x 4
#  column_a column_b         country_code country      
#  <chr>    <list>           <chr>        <chr>        
#1 a        <named list [9]> US           United States
#2 b        <named list [9]> UG           Uganda       
#3 c        <named list [9]> US           United States
```

---

If we need to extract the full columns

```
library(tibble)
foo %>%
    mutate(out = map(column_b, enframe)) %>% 
    unnest(out) %>% 
    spread(name, value) %>%
    unnest(setdiff(names(.), c("column_b", "attributes","bounding_box")))
# A tibble: 3 x 11
#  column_a column_b      attributes     bounding_box    country    country_code full_name    id         name     place_type url                             
#  <chr>    <list>        <list>         <list>          <chr>      <chr>        <chr>        <chr>      <chr>    <chr>      <chr>                           
#1 a        <named list … <named list [… <named list [2… United St… US           Austin, TX   c3f37afa9… Austin   city       https://api.twitter.com/1.1/geo…
#2 b        <named list … <named list [… <named list [2… Uganda     UG           Wakiso, Uga… 0092409a6… Wakiso   admin      https://api.twitter.com/1.1/geo…
#3 c        <named list … <named list [… <named list [2… United St… US           Bloomington… 080b8d854… Bloomin… city       https://api.twitter.com/1.1/geo…
```

Comment: This seems to be a very good approach! Is there a way to avoid calling all the variables one by one?

Comment: Could you please post this solution? It would be great. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @TitoSanz If you have some other way you need to select or exclude columns, you can use some `dplyr` select helpers or base methods, but that should be in your question

Comment: @akrun sorry if my question was not clear, but my it specifically says without calling all variables one by one. Is there a way? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @TitoSanz  If you can show the expected output in your post, it would be useful.  Otherwise, I would be doing all the work and then you will come up and ssay it is not the expected.

Comment: @akrun the desired output is the same as in Solution B but without NAs. Of course, I will upvote and mark your answer.

Comment: @TitoSanz  The isssue I have is `oo$column_b[[1]]$bounding_box$coordinates
, , 1

          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]
[1,] -97.92893 -97.92893 -97.58051 -97.58051

, , 2

         [,1]    [,2]    [,3]     [,4]
[1,] 30.12789 30.5188 30.5188 30.12789`  I don't know how you want the structure in output.  it i a 3d array

Comment: @akrun Any solution is valid: keep it as a column of lists, or undo the list. Whatever easier...

Comment: @TitoSanz  If you are okay with column of lists, then `foo %>% mutate(out = map(column_b, enframe)) %>% unnest(out) %>% spread(name, value)`

Comment: @akrun the answer is excellent till the call to `unnest`, this is the error: Error: Column `setdiff(names(.), c("column_b", "attributes", "bounding_box"))` must be length 3 (the number of rows) or one, not 8

Comment: @TitoSanz  Is it the same data on which the function is applied or different one that causeed the error.  For me, it is working fine on `dpyr_0.8.3` `purrr-0.3.2` and `tidyr` ‘0.8.3.9000’

Comment: @TitoSanz  I am using the devel version of `tidyr`.  unnest is from tidyr.  So, may be the behavior changed

Comment: @akrun You are totally right, I updated all the packages to the dev version and now it works. Thanks for all.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `jsonlite` trick (converting back and forth to use the power of `fromJSON`).
Also, was the data originally JSON? If yes, `fromJSON(flatten = TRUE)` *directly* might be more sensible.

```
library(jsonlite)

foo$column_b %>% 
  toJSON(auto_unbox = TRUE) %>% 
  fromJSON(flatten = TRUE) 
# Observations: 3
# Variables: 9
# $ country_code             <chr> "US", "UG", "US"
# $ url                      <chr> "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/geo/id/c3f37afa…
# $ country                  <chr> "United States", "Uganda", "United States"
# $ place_type               <chr> "city", "admin", "city"
# $ full_name                <chr> "Austin, TX", "Wakiso, Uganda", "Bloomington…
# $ id                       <chr> "c3f37afa9efcf94b", "0092409a629e836c", "080…
# $ name                     <chr> "Austin", "Wakiso", "Bloomington"
# $ bounding_box.type        <chr> "Polygon", "Polygon", "Polygon"
# $ bounding_box.coordinates <list> [<array[1 x 4 x 2]>, <array[1 x 4 x 2]>, <a…
```